# Kendo UI Filter is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, kendo-ui, viewmodel

I want to use Kendo UI grid with filter option in APS.NET MVC.

In my example I use database as datasource and a student table

When I use student class as

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var std = (from p in db.Students
                select p).ToList();
        return View("Student", std);
    }
```

everything is ok.

But when I want use ViewModel as datasource, in runtime when I click in filter icon filter window open but I can't see anything in dropdown list of filter.

I use automapper and value injecter.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

### Appended

### PersonController.cs

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{

    Adventureworks2012DataContext db = new Adventureworks2012DataContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        /*var prs = (from p in db.Person
                   select p).ToList();*/
        return View(GetPersonViewModel());
    }

    public ActionResult PersonViewModel_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(GetPersonViewModel().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    private  IList<PersonViewModel> GetPersonViewModel()
    {
        return db.Person.Project().To<PersonViewModel>().ToList();
    }    
}
```

### Index.cshtml

```
@model IList<DevartLinqTestMVC.ViewModel.PersonViewModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Person List";}

<br />
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Businessentityid);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Persontype);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Namestyle);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Title);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Firstname);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Middlename);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Lastname);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Emailpromotion);
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .Selectable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Model(m => m.Id(s => s.Businessentityid))
                                    .PageSize(20)
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("PersonViewModel_Read", "Person")))
)
```

[everything is good also ajax work perfectly](http://www.overpic.net/viewer.php?file=xwlutk24at0n6eyvsw0kf.jpg)

[but where is filter dropdown list?!!!](http://www.overpic.net/viewer.php?file=xwmyo36ddcbju84ilk2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a list in your view it only works you want a static list that is loaded once. If you want server side paging or a toolbar, you need to load your data using a server side function that returns a JSON object and link it to your grid with .Read().

For example, in your controller (code not tested):

```
    public ActionResult StudentGrid_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json((from p in db.Students select p).ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

And on your grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .[other stuff]
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .[other stuff]
        .Read("StudentGrid_Read", "Controller")
    )
)
```

See the kendo ui grid with toolbar demo for the complete coding example: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/toolbar-template.html

Edit: just noticed there is a filtering demo as well, but the idea is the same:
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html

Comment: I do something like this everything work good. only filter list is empty

Comment: If the you set this up properly, you should be able to pass an empty list:

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Student", null);
    }

If you pass a non-empty list, your grid is filled up with data, but may not work properly. If you pass an empty list and you get no data it should be an indication that something in your setup isn't exactly right. (I have had similar trouble with server side paging and it can be a pain to debug)

Comment: oh no
I said my problem is with .filterable property in my work everything is ok but when I click on filter icon, filter window open but nothing show in dropdown list Start with,End with and ... therefore I can't filter data

Comment: Try the following: return Json(GetPersonViewModel().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);